# Cannot insert image into Media database

Tags: android

The following code allows me to take pictures, however it does not insert the image into the db. What am I missing?

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put(Media.TITLE, "Image");
values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_ID, "292");
values.put(Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, "thename");
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
values.put(Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image capture by camera");
values.put("_data", IMG_FILE_PATH);
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert( Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI , values);
i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
i.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(i,REQ_PHOTO);
```

Comment: values.put("_data", IMG_FILE_PATH);

Perhaps try removing this. _data is where your file gets stored so when you take the picture, pre-inserting this may mess it up.

Comment: Additionally, do you need to pre-insert all of those values? I have an image capture intent that is 4 lines long and works perfectly

Comment: Can you paste your capture code in answer? would love to give you points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new ContentValues());     
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(imageIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY);
```

Try just using this code. It seems like you overwriting _data is causing issues when Android tries to store the image.

Comment: These images don't appear immediately in the gallery. After mounting/unmounting my sdcard, somehow this causes some magic refresh of the gallery. This is a side-effect and not a solution. you must be leaving something out?

Comment: Try taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2870906/adding-pictures-to-the-gallery-android